# Setting minimum time between consecutive reparses by semantic

Tags: semantic-mode, parse-time

According to the Semantic [docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/semantic.html), `semantic-edit.el` is the file which handles all incremental parsing. I see frequent incremental parse errors(not information messages, since I have `semantic-edits-verbose-flag` `nil`) and would like to set a minimum time interval between consecutive reparses of my cpp files. Other than `semantic-edits-verbose-flag`, I don't see any `defcustom`'s in `semantic-edit.el`. Is there a way of customizing this behaviour?

Comment: Have you tried `semantic-idle-scheduler-idle-time`? Semantic should parse only when Emacs is idle.

Comment: @TuDo That did the trick. Could you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semantic should parse only when Emacs is idle. The variable `semantic-idle-scheduler-idle-time` is the amount of idle time, in seconds, before the Semantic idle scheduler activates.